# Mongoose.js find yesterday's date in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I want to find all the users created up until yesterday. This is my code to make the query string:

```
var today = new Date();
var a = today.getDate();
a--;
today.setDate(a);
var yesterday = today.toDateString();
```

and it returns something like: Sun Jan 17 2016... which IS yesterday's date, but the db stores the date in iso format like: `"date" : ISODate("2016-01-13T13:23:08.419Z")` so what I get is `2016-01-13T13:23:08.419Z`. My problem now is that I can't use the yesterday variable to query the db for the users I need AND even if I could, I don't know how to find every registration not including the ones that took place today.

Any help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are generating a date on the front end, and then pushing it back a day, which is totally fine for a lot of circumstances -

For this, since you are trying to find DB entries that occured, perhaps try querying the database with a timestamp ranged pulled from the ID's of each document in your database.

Here is some documentation on how to do that from mongoDB. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/

I've also provided some additional resources that may help you figure out exactly what to query in regard to this method:

https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

https://gist.github.com/tebemis/0e55aa0089e928f362d9

Some psuedo code:

```
1. Query documents in the database
2. Get a timestamp from the ID's of the documents in the database
3. Set a range of the timestamps
4. Compare returned timestamps vs a timestamp range variable (yesterdays date in this case)
5. Have the DB return only documents that are within the range
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
yesterday = moment().add(-1, 'days');
db.users.find({ "date": { "$lt": yesterday }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a date object that represents the start of day today, use it to query your collection for documents where the `date` field is less than that variable, as in the following example

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

db.users.find({ "date": { "$lt": start }});
```

This will look for users created up until end of day yesterday.

**[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)** is a super handy utility for doing manipulations like this. Using the library, this can be achieved with the [**`startOf()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) method on the moment's current date object, passing the string `'day'` as arguments:

**Local GMT:**

```
var start = moment().startOf('day'); // set to 12:00 am today
db.users.find({ "date": { "$lt": start }});
```

[**For UTC:**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

```
var start = moment.utc().startOf('day');
```